# Attributes values are not showing at admin panel after adding them from database magento2

Tags: magento2, admin, custom-attributes

I have created a new product attribute warehouse_country and inserted values from database. But these vales are not showing at admin panel.See image 1
[image]

And I want to use this attribute for layered navigation filter but not able to change "Use in Layered Navigation". this is disabled. See image 2

[image]

Comment: where are the images?

Comment: Please check now

Comment: `I have created a new product attribute warehouse_country and inserted values from database. But these vales are not showing at admin panel.` - which admin panel? do you mean product listing?

Comment: `And I want to use this attribute for layered navigation filter but not able to change "Use in Layered Navigation". this is disabled.` - you should read the description below the option, it states that only dropdown, multiple select, and price are able to be used in layered navigation.

Comment: Yes, but I am able to show quantity filter at frontend in layered navigation

Comment: have a look at this docs https://docs.magento.com/m2/ee/user_guide/catalog/navigation-layered-filterable-attributes.html